# How does Frontapp's checkup count the number of sent emails?

Tags: gmail

https://checkup.frontapp.com allows to scan a Gmail inbox to get some basic activity metrics.

[image]

I see the number of sent emails over the last 100 days is totally underestimated if I compare with https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#sent/. How does Frontapp's count the number of sent emails?

---

Using the request `from:(franck.dernoncourt@gmail.com) after:2014/8/22 before:2014/10/23`, I see I sent emails in 420 different threads over the last 30 months, which is more than Frontapp's checkup count of number of sent emails:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alice from Front here! We count the number of emails that have a "sent" label on them over the last 100 days in your inbox. (so basically all the emails with your address in the "from" field). Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Alice, I added in the question a screenshot showing that I sent more emails that what Front reported. Any idea?